# UDP server on LwIP socket falls into hard fault if input string longer than 19 bytes

Tags: c, sockets, freertos, lwip, stm32f4

I think it because of NULL pointer exception. My embedded system consists of STM32F4, FreeRTOS and LwIP. Core was taken from ST example. Here is the code of thread of simple UDP server.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lwip/sockets.h"
#include "./udpCLI.h"
//#include "Sledge.h" //for assert_amsg(), which print what and where fails before stop execution

static void udpCLI_thread(void *arg) 
{
    int sockfd; // socket file descriptor
    const uint16_t serverport = UDP_PORT_NUMBER_CLI;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr = {0}, clientaddr = {0};
    socklen_t addrlen;// = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    const uint16_t bufin_SIZE = 200, bufout_SIZE = 1024;
    char *bufin  = malloc(bufin_SIZE);  assert_amsg(bufin != NULL);  // stops execution with printing message "ASSERT FAILED "bufin != NULL" in file udp_cli.c:42" in stdout/stderr
    char *bufout = malloc(bufout_SIZE); assert_amsg(bufout != NULL);

    LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(arg);  //(void)arg;

    debugf2( "udpCLI_thread"NEWLINE );  

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    assert_msg("udpCLI_thread: ERROR opening socket", sockfd>=0);

    /*
     * build the server's Internet address
     */
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(serverport);

    /* 
     * bind: associate the socket with a port 
     */
    if( bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0 ) 
        error("udpCLI_thread: ERROR on binding");

    // main loop: wait for a datagram, then echo it
    while(1)
    {
        addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);  // THIS DID NOT HELP
        // recvfrom: receive a UDP datagram from a client
        int n = recvfrom(sockfd, bufin, bufin_SIZE, /*flags*/0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr, &addrlen);
        // handle rusult
        //if (n < 0)
        // future process and response
        //....
}
```

Program control never returns from `recvfrom()` function if input message length is more than 19 bytes. And never returns from function `sys_arch_mbox_fetch(&conn->recvmbox, &buf, 0);` in function `netconn_recv_data()` in file `api_lib.c` at line `371`.
Please help to resolve this problem.

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* in the code you show, as you never initialize `addrlen`. It must be initialize before each call to `recvfrom`.

Comment: Also, doing `sizeof` on a pointer gives you the size of the pointer (usually 4 or 8 bytes, depending on 32 or 64 bit architecture), not what it points to.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings.  (for `gcc` at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: when you ask a question about a runtime error, always post code the 1) is compact/small 2) cleanly compiles, 3) still exhibits the problem.  4) contains the needed `#include` statements, (so we do not have guess as to what headers you included)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: after the calls to `malloc()` the `assert()` statements will not tell you the reason for the failure.  Strongly suggest (one statement per line) use code similar to: `if( !bufin ) { perror( "malloc failed for input buffer" );  //cleanup then `exit( EXIT_FAILURE); }`   where perror() is found in stdio.h, exit() and EXIT_FAILURE found in stdlib.h

Comment: the parameter to `malloc()` is expected to be a `size_t`, not a `const uint16_t`.

Comment: the definition of the variables: `bufin_SIZE` and `bufout_SIZE`  are just cluttering the stack.  much better to use a `enum` statement of two `#define` statements to give those numbers meaningful names

Comment: the proper way to write the signature of a thread function is: `void * threadName( void * parmName)`   (and not `static`) so the signature should be: `void *udpCLI_thread( void *arg )`   and for portability of handling the unused parameter.  the first line of the function body should be: `(void)arg;`

Comment: this line: `error("udpCLI_thread: ERROR in recvfrom");`  should not result in execution dropping down to after the `if/else`  instead, insert: `continue;` after that line.

Comment: strongly suggest using `select()` before diving into the `recvfrom()` statement.

Comment: in the code block: `else if( n==0 )`, do not call `continue;` because the client as closed its' connection.  excerpt from the man page: `The  return  value  will  be  0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown.`  and the text: `else` can be removed.   Suggest using: `break;` rather than `continue;`

Comment: why bother to NUL terminate the bufin[] array?  on the call to `sendto()` the variable 'len` is not defined anywhere in the posted code. suggest using the `n` variable that was set by the call to `recvfrom()`

Comment: the returned type from `recvfrom()` is a `ssize_t`, not an `int`

Comment: the type for the 'len' parameter to `sendto()` is an `size_t`, not an `int`

Comment: `int lwip_recvfrom(int s, void *mem, size_t len, int flags, struct sockaddr *from, socklen_t *fromlen)` and `#define recvfrom(a,b,c,d,e,f) lwip_recvfrom(a,b,c,d,e,f)` from `lwip/sockets.h`.

Comment: @user3629249 , > *the variable 'len` is not defined anywhere in the posted code* <
`uint16_t len = strlen( bufout );`

Comment: @user3629249, *the proper way to write the signature of a thread function is*  FreeRTOS and most RTOSes I met, think that `typedef void (*lwip_thread_fn)(void *arg);`  and `typedef void (*TaskFunction_t)( void * );` means that tread/task function returns nothing, not `void*`.

Comment: @user3629249, thank you for your comments but all of them don't help to solve problem. They are common to code style but not decisive.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I added `addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);` before `recvfrom`, but that gave no effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113713/discussion-between-kyb-and-user3629249).

Comment: @user3629249 This is UDP. There is no connection.  A return value of zero in UDP means a zero-length datagram, not a disconnect.

Comment: @kyb Your question doesn't make sense. If the first `malloc()` gives a SIGSEGV or whatever it is, how did you get to execute `recvfrom()`? Please clarify.

Comment: @EJP, If my `malloc()` fails, or gets any exception program execution will be stopped. Memory manager is from FreeRTOS. It has no stdlib and BSD support. Only OK or fail.

Comment: and the same thing with other example http://my.fit.edu/~vkepuska/ece3551/ADI_Speedway_Golden/Blackfin%20Speedway%20Manuals/LwIP/socket-api/udp-cli-serv.html

Comment: So how did you get as far as `recvfrom()`? You haven't clarified what I asked you to clarify.

Comment: @EJP, `malloc` works fine. I can use static or stack buffers and problem will not disappear. Tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my mistake. The problem was with wrong memory allocation and release in another task.
*I thank all who sympathized.*